# What is the best software for neural network analysis?

Tags: r, spss, neural-networks, software

I need to fit a neural network to my data.

I used SPSS 21, but I think it's model summary isn't sufficient.

I also used R (nnet & neuralnet), it has a poor report and I can't find a good model summary for it.

The last one is NeuroSolutions, I used it. very bad! I can't run a model. What are those graphical icons in it's window after bulding model?

You say! What's your advice for Neural Network Analysis?

Comment: I've voted to close this question (along with 2 others) because the question solicits opinion. Whilst some questions seek opinion-based answers, those that rely solely on those opinions are considered OT for [stats.se]. If the question can be backed up with experience, supported by other facts etc, then it *may* be on topic. At the moment your question purely seeks advice and such questions are not a good fit for any of the [se] sites. If you can reformulate the question to be more specific, it may not be closed (or could be reopened).